# Like to compare date not working

Tags: oracle, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise library 6.0 in my project to execute queries in a Oracle database.

When I execute the command bellow no records are found:

```
SELECT ACS.COD_IDENT_FMACO,
               ACO.NOM_IDENT_ACO,
               ACS.COD_CICLO_SIGA,
               to_char(ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
               ACS.SEQ_PROCE_ALOC,
               UM.COD_UNIMET_PCP,
               UM.COD_UNIMET_SIP,
               PERR.ESP_UNIMET_ETAPA,
               PERR.LAR_UNIMET_ETAPA,
               PERR.COM_UNIMET_ETAPA,
               PERR.PES_LIQUIDO,
               ACS.COD_INTER_PEDCL,
               ACS.COD_ITEM_PEDCL,
               IP.NUM_PEDID_MAINF,
               C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN,
               C.NOM_ABREV_PESSO,
               IP.DAT_MAIOR_PLANE,
               PD.COD_GRUPO_PROAC,
               PD.COD_QUASU_PROAC,
               PER.VLR_TOMIN_ESPES,
               PER.ESP_MM_PRODT,
               PER.VLR_TOMAX_ESPES,
               PER.VLR_TOMIN_LARGU,
               PER.LAR_MM_PROAC,
               PER.VLR_TOMAX_LARGU,
               ACS.PES_ALOC_SIGA,
               IP.PES_MINIM_DESEJ,
               IP.PES_DESEJ_ITEM,
               IP.PES_MAXIM_DESEJ,
               PD.PES_MIN_PACOT,
               PD.PES_MAX_PACOT
        FROM PR_ALOC_CICLO_SIGA ACS,
             PR_PRODUTO_ETAPA_ROTINA_REALIZ PERR,
             CM_ITEM_PC IP,
             CM_CLIENTE C,
             PR_ROTINA_FABRC R,
             PR_ETAPA_ROTINA ER,
             PR_PRODT_ETAPA_ROT PER,
             PR_PRODUTO PD,
             PR_UNIDADE_METALICA UM,
             PR_ACO ACO
        WHERE ACS.COD_INTER_PEDCL = IP.COD_INTER_PEDCL
          AND ACS.COD_ITEM_PEDCL = IP.COD_ITEM_PEDCL
          AND IP.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN
          AND ACS.COD_CICLO_SIGA = '60'
          AND ER.COD_AREA_PROCE = 'Q'
          AND ER.COD_OPERA_FABRC IN('TQ007',
                                    'TQ013')
          AND IP.COD_INTER_PEDCL = R.NUM_IDENT_PEDID
          AND IP.COD_ITEM_PEDCL = R.NUM_ITEM_PEDID
          AND R.NUM_ROTIN_FABRC = ER.NUM_ROTIN_FABRC
          AND R.NUM_VERSA_ROTIN = ER.NUM_VERSA_ROTIN
          AND R.IDC_SITUA_ROTIN IN ('A',
                                    'P')
          AND R.IDC_SITUA_ROTIN = 'A'
          AND ER.NUM_ROTIN_FABRC = PER.NUM_ROTIN_FABRC
          AND ER.NUM_VERSA_ROTIN = PER.NUM_VERSA_ROTIN
          AND ER.NUM_ETAPA_ROTIN = PER.NUM_ETAPA_ROTIN
          AND IP.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = PD.COD_IDENT_CLIEN
          AND IP.COD_LINHA_PRODT = PD.COD_LINHA_PRODT
          AND IP.NUM_SEQ_PRODT = PD.NUM_SEQ_PRODT
          AND IP.NUM_SEQ_REVIS = PD.NUM_SEQ_REVIS
          AND ACS.COD_UNIMET_PCP = UM.COD_UNIMET_PCP
          AND UM.COD_UNIMET_PCP = PERR.COD_UNIMET_PCP
          AND PERR.SEQ_ETAPA_ROTINA_REALIZADA = UM.SEQ_ULTIM_ETAPA
          AND PD.COD_IDENT_ACO = ACO.COD_IDENT_ACO
          AND ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO LIKE TO_DATE('15/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
          AND 'I' LIKE '%'||IP.COD_LINHA_PRODT|| '%'
          AND IP.COD_LINHA_PRODT IS NOT NULL
          AND 1 = 1
        ORDER BY IP.COD_INTER_PEDCL,
                 IP.COD_ITEM_PEDCL,
                 IP.NUM_PEDID_MAINF
```

But if I change the line

```
AND ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO LIKE TO_DATE('15/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

by

```
AND ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO BETWEEN TO_DATE('15/10/2015'||'00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                       AND     TO_DATE('15/10/2015'||'23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

the results are returned correct.

There are any config to do in C# or enterprise library to understand this command?

Note: I need to execute with like because we are upgrading a system and this change cause different sort order in records.

Comment: Is the data type of the column `ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO` some sort of character data type, such as `VARCHAR2`? (If so, make sure when you upgrade the system you correct this as well; dates should be in the `DATE` data type.) In any case, you have `TO_DATE` on the right-hand side; since `LIKE` compares strings, the result of `TO_DATE` (which is a date) is implicitly converted to a string, using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter. You could change that to 'DD/MM/YYYY' and your query may then work, despite the cumulation of bad practices.

Comment: The column ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO is DateTime. If I execute the query with like in SQL Developer, for example, the result is showed, but the order the data are different.

Comment: Of course, if you are comparing to a **fixed** date, then on the right-hand side you don't need `TO_DATE()` at all, you just need the string `'15/01/2015'`.

Comment: There is no DateTime data type in Oracle. Instead of guessing, please run `DESCRIBE ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO` and see what data type the column is really in.

Comment: Which version of Oracle database?

Comment: Sorry, the type is DATE. Oracle 11.2.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO LIKE TO_DATE('15/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Will do a string comparison between the two date and will convert them both to strings using an implicit call to the `TO_CHAR( datevalue, format_mask )` function using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask.

If this is set to include the time component then it will only match rows where the time component is `00:00:00`.

```
AND ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO BETWEEN TO_DATE('15/10/2015'||'00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                       AND     TO_DATE('15/10/2015'||'23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Will compare the the values as dates (and will be able to use indexes on the column).

You could also do:

```
AND ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO >= DATE '2015-10-15'
AND ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO <  DATE '2015-10-15' + INTERVAL '1' DAY -- or DATE '2015-10-16'
```

> I need to execute with like because we are upgrading a system and this change cause different sort order in records.

If you are required to use `LIKE` then you could do:

```
TO_CHAR( ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) LIKE '15/10/2015'
```

However, changing the filter conditions should not change the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting my original answer because, having tested it on 12c, it turns out that this works.

```
where date_col like to_date('2017/04/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Even though my NLS setting is not `'yyyy/mm/dd'`.

You learn something new every day.

Comment: On 11g with `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` as `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` I can't get `LIKE` to match unless the dates are exactly identical.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because the ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO field probably has times in there which is not exactly at 00:00:00. The easy way to get around this is by using trunc().

```
AND TRUNC(ACS.DTH_ALOC_CICLO) = TO_DATE('15/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
```